# Reading Excel file into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm reading (asp.net mvc c# site) an excel file with multiple worksheets into a sql database where the first sheet goes into table A and an auto-increment column generates a unique id or PK.

Now the second worksheet goes into TABLE B but it has a composite key made up of auto-increment column for TABLE B and the value from Table A.

My question is how do I get Table A's PK into Table B while reading the excel file?

I'm not sure if this question is better suited for database design or c#.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're doing your insert, you could run a query like

```
SELECT scope_identity()
```

which will get your last inserted PK.